# C# MVC: Return ViewModel or Model Class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

let's say I have a view where I currently only use Model information from my "User" class.

Should I still create an extra viewmodel wrapper or directly return the user class instance to the view?

**Directly returned object:**

```
return View(user);
```

**Wrapped in ViewModel object:**

```
return View(new UserViewModel(user));
```

I'm looking for the best practice here. Maybe I need to return more info later to the view, but I dont know that yet. Would that still be argument to always use an extra ViewModel class though?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you should not use View Model if you are using information only from Model. It is a simple situation. Create strongly-typed View and use your Model directly.

Comment: Even in terms of extensibility? Because it would be much easier to add another field to a VM in case I ever need it.

Comment: I dont think that it will be much easier to add new field to VM than create VM. In both cases you shoud plan your modification and then create test for it. In general I think that in every situation the simplest solution is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use a domain model until I need a view model. Why? Using the domain model is faster up front. Then, when the domain model no longer covers my need, I refactor, adding what I need where I need it. I'm a big fan of "get it working quickly and refactor vigorously".

This also goes for splitting models into multiple user controls.